# edit apa.bst to show et al. in bibliography when authors>10 and use initials without periods

Tags: natbib, bibliographystyle, bst

I am trying to edit the [apa.bst](https://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/bibtex/apa.bst) style to match a journal guideline style and I need to make two changes:

1. If there are more than ten authors, the reference entry should list the first ten authors followed by “et al.”. Example:

   > Author AZ, Author BY, Author CX, Author DW, Author EV, Author FU, Author GT, Author HS, Author IR, Author JQ, et al. (2017). Research Title. Journal, Vol:1–12.
2. For all authors, use initials, without periods or spaces between them (e.g. "Author MPJ" instead of "Author, M. P. J.")

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I assume you're aware that the `apa` bibliography style is quite ancient and does not come close to implementing the two most recent vintages -- "6" and "7", respectively -- of the APA's guidelines for citation call-outs and formatted bibliographic entries. If the journal you're working with is fine with vintage-6 formatting, give the `apacite` citation management package and the `apacite` bibliography style a go. If your journal requires vintage-7 formatting, then you'll have to switch to the `biblatex-apa` package and biber.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The journal I'm working with has specific guidelines for the bibliography and I am not sure if they correspond to a named reference style. The apa was the most similar one that I found, so I thought I can start with it as a baseline and edit it to journal style. Can I do this with the biblatex-apa package?